# How does the iPhone 3.5 mm port work with regards to input?

Tags: iphone, hardware, headphones

Due to the recent death of Pebble, I am making plans for a custom built smart watch that actually has buttons (seriously, try finding a smart watch without a touch screen) which will probably never be sold due to my priority for personal preference. One of my prototype designs has the watch connected through the 3.5 mm port (on an older phone obviously). I know data input through the 3.5 mm is possible because the Square Card Reader uses it as well as most quality headphones with the pause button/mic. I have torn apart an older set of Apple standard headphones and found that there are five internal wires (green, green striped, red, red striped, and green and red striped) plus a white plastic core. I haven't been able to figure out which goes to which ring yet but that should be easy to figure out with a bit more dissecting.

From my understanding the rings are, in order from tip up, ground/left/right/button with ground being split into two so that it can go to each bud. I may be off a little on the order here.

What I want to know is, which rings are the iPhone able to understand input from? I know it can take input from the ring linked to the button, but can it also take input from the other two rings? Or can it only send output on those?

Comment: Note that you can't send data over the 3.5mm jack (via the mic) per se. Square Readers generate an analog audio signal when swiping the card and then do interesting signal processing to interpret that audio signal.

Comment: Good to know. Is the button on the earbuds also translated into analog? I only need a few buttons so analog conversion would be weird but not too bad.

Comment: @unknown the button presses are analog I believe. Also, I miss pebble :(